# jQuery- attr/value not retrieving a value as number but NaN

Tags: jquery, attr

I'm trying to make a button that returns a value as a number when clicked. However it returns NaN. Could anyone tell what went wrong?

```
         <div class="card-body">
            <button id="button-1" class="btn btn-primary number" value="1">
              <h1>1</h1>
            </button>

         </div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        $(document).ready(function () {

           var userBtnValue = ($(this).attr("value"));
           userBtnValue = parseInt(userBtnValue);
           console.log(userBtnValue);


    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you forgot to write the onclick function for the button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '#button-1', function() {
    var userBtnValue = ($(this).attr("value"));
    userBtnValue = parseInt(userBtnValue);
    console.log(userBtnValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <button id="button-1" class="btn btn-primary number" value="1">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </button>
</div>
```

This will give you your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

### `$( document ).ready()`

You simply need to refer to the button using the button id `#button-1`, instead of using `this` when trying to get the button attribute `value` inside the `$(document).ready` directly. As `this` inside the `$(document).ready` refers to the `document` instead of the button with id `#button-1`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var userBtnValue = $("#button-1").attr("value");
  userBtnValue = parseInt(userBtnValue);
  console.log(userBtnValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <button id="button-1" class="btn btn-primary number" value="1">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </button>
</div>
```

---

### `.click()`

Your code `$(this).attr("value")` will only work if we have a click event listener for that button, as in that case `this` will always refer to the click button:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event,
  $("#button-1").click(function() {
    var userBtnValue = $(this).attr("value");
    userBtnValue = parseInt(userBtnValue);
    console.log(userBtnValue);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <button id="button-1" class="btn btn-primary number" value="1">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </button>
</div>
```